# Java code to run data from acrobat distiller

Tags: java, acrobat

I am writing a program which should select .txt files from a selected directory and print them using Acrobat Distiller. At present, I can select and open all the files but then  I get only the first file printed and this error: System.out.println("COMPLETED") whitout completing any of other print out.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;


public class acrobat {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        File foldertotalcountletters = new File("C:\\Users\\JayRaj\\workspace\\auto\\proof\\US\\letter\\07-01-2013");
        File[] listOfFilestotalcountletters = foldertotalcountletters.listFiles();

        String totalcountletters;

        try{

            for (int itotalcount = 0; itotalcount < listOfFilestotalcountletters.length; itotalcount++) {
                if (listOfFilestotalcountletters[itotalcount].isFile()) {

                    totalcountletters = listOfFilestotalcountletters[itotalcount].getName();

                    System.out.println(totalcountletters);

                    Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();
                    Process process = runTime.exec("acrodist");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e25) {
                e25.printStackTrace();
            }

    }

}
```

This is a more detailed content of the error.

```
Proof_US_30189650_06-29-13_mail_RecordCount_56.txt.txt
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "acrodist.exe": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Unknown Source)
    at acrobat.main(acrobat.java:24)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(Unknown Source)
    ... 5 more
```

I have no idea what to do to get all the selected files printed out.

Comment: And the question? Which is the problem? What you would like to achieve?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to write program to run all the file in folder run from acrobat first part its working System.out.println(filename) its working but.. second part getting error.. After print first file give me error.. Please help me.. run all files from acrobat dist..after completed all files from acrobat dist. say completed..